# running a function on each cell in a matrix, knowing the index a cell, without using loops

Tags: arrays, function, matlab, loops, matrix

I have a function F that receives an 2D index (i and j) and a constant array C. I want to run this function on each cell in a matrix, meaning - in the (i,j) cell I'll have the value F(i,j,C).

Is there a way to do it in matlab without using loops?

Comment: Have a look at [cellfun](http://www.mathworks.ch/help/techdoc/ref/cellfun.html) and [arrayfun](http://www.mathworks.ch/help/techdoc/ref/arrayfun.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply a function to every item in an array or matrix, use `arrayfun`.

```
m = [1:3; 4:6];
arrayfun(@(x) x + 1, m)
```

To use arrayfun, you need to modify the signature of your function `F` so that it takes the item in your matrix at (i,j), not the indicies themselves.

Also, a purely vectorised solution is often faster than using `arrayfun`.  For example, compare

```
tic; for(i = 1:1000); mean(m(:)); end; toc
tic; for(i = 1:1000); arrayfun(@mean, m); end; toc
```

Comment: I need to sample a function into an array, therefore I need the coordinates of each cell in order to sample the function into it. So I can't do the modification you've suggested. I'm trying to avoid loops in order to speed up the process.